# How can I solve this react-native iOS problem?

Tags: xcode

How can I solve this react-native iOs problem?

```
Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin)
    at new FSEventsWatcher (/Users/krushitpatel/geniussch/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/sane/src/fsevents_watcher.js:37:13)
    at createWatcher (/Users/krushitpatel/geniussch/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:923:23)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HasteMap._watch (/Users/krushitpatel/geniussch/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1088:44)
    at /Users/krushitpatel/geniussch/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:463:23
```

Comment: Did you solve this, I have the same issue!